# How to run GUI apps with Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running a Windows 10 computer and have recently installed Windows Subsystem for Linux. This generally creates a single terminal with no "display" environment. It seems that Tmux can be used to get several terminals, but this doesn't let you use any sort of graphical display.

I'd like to open a Linux browser, such as Firefox, through Windows Subsystem for Linux.

I tried the suggestions [here](http://rolandtanglao.com/2019/01/02/p1-howto-make-firefox-work-on-wsl/), but I just get the error:

```
no DISPLAY environment variable specified
```

Comment: Please provide which version of WSL your WSL instance is configured to.  We also need to know what version of Windows 10 you are running.

Comment: It is 2022 now, and you can update to the windows 10 version 21H2 (which is latest). And then run this command to update wsl: ```wsl --update```. Then you can directly run GUI apps.

Answer (score 8):

See Ubuntu wiki [Running Graphical Applications](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL#Running_Graphical_Applications).

You need to install *on Windows* an X-server to be launched *from Windows*
to be used by WSL graphical applications.

You may use any of X410, VcXsrv, MobaXTerm, Cygwin/C, Xming, Cygwin X, vcXsrv.

If graphical applications can't connect to the running X server automatically paste the following commands to the terminal before starting the applications or set them on every login by adding them to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export DISPLAY=:0 # in WSL 1
export DISPLAY=$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2>/dev/null):0 # in WSL 2
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
```

Another useful article is
[Running Graphical Programs on Windows Subsystem on Linux](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2017/02/08/graphical-programs-on-windows-subsystem-on-linux.aspx).

Comment: This is not working in my case.

Comment: @71GA: There are more recent answers in this post than mine.

Answer (score 6):

*Adding an answer with more recent information than was available at the time the question was originally asked, primarily because I'm linking to this question/answer for other duplicates (here and on Stack Overflow, where it's general an off-topic question).*

There are (at least) three options:

- With the release of WSL 1.0.0 (WSL via Microsoft Store application), both Windows 10 and Windows 11 users have full access to WSLg, which allows Linux GUI applications (X or Wayland) to run directly on WSL2 with no additional configuration.  Prior to 1.0.0, this feature was limited to Windows 11 users.

  Windows 10 users will need to be on a build ending in `.2311` or higher, which currently means installing [KB5020030](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/november-15-2022-kb5020030-os-builds-19042-2311-19043-2311-19044-2311-and-19045-2311-preview-237a9048-f853-4e29-a3a2-62efdbea95e2).  If the final four digits of your build number are lower than 2311, make sure your Windows is up-to-date, then find KB5020030 in the *Optional Updates*.

  Once on an up-to-date Windows 10 or Windows 11 system, you can either install WSL from its [Microsoft Store page](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage) or ...

  ```
  wsl --install
  # or, if already installed
  wsl --update
  # confirm 1.0.0 or later via:
  wsl --version
  ```
- A legacy alternative is the one that harrymc offers of installing a third-party X server.  I won't repeat the information on how to do so since it's already covered in that answer, although I will say that `export DISPLAY=$(hostname).local:0` will typically work, and is more concise.  This uses mDNS as I go into detail on in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407064/11810933).
- Finally, if you want to run a Linux *desktop* under WSL, you might want to consider RDP.  You can install `xrdp` and just access a Linux desktop using Windows Remote Desktop connection.  See my steps for doing so in [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365455/1165986).  Note that only `xfce` is really necessary, although the answer includes more detail on running something more complex like Gnome Desktop.

Answer (score 4):

**Remove all *export DISPLAY* settings in your startup files!**

It's not needed anymore.

With recent WSL (Windows 10 Build 19044+ or Win 11), the system takes care of that.

I repeat.

**You do no longer need to export the DISPLAY variable!**

Prior to reading the official documentation, linked in MOMO's answer, I had tried all the fancy ways of getting the DISPLAY value automatically set posted by others, and nothing worked.

**Backstory**

I, and many with me, use non-default name servers, so I can't use that trick to refer to my local system. Instead I have a static value for IPv6 localhost in /etc/hosts.

```
# This is to always have a named host address for servers on WSL, like sshd
# Usually I use 127.0.0.1 instead.
::1     wsl
```

And the same in Windows c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Then I *had* set the DISPLAY variable in ~/.bashrc like this.

```
export DISPLAY=wsl:0.0
```

When testing both *thunderbird* and *mousepad* start fine.

But if I tried to start *firefox/firefox-esr* I got failed access to DISPLAY.

```
$ firefox-esr
Error: cannot open display: wsl:0.0
```

Basically, thunderbird *never* cared what DISPLAY was set to. Perhaps that is why it worked for me. It started even back when the variable *was* set to the wrong IP.

**But, now, with *no* DISPLAY variable manually set, firefox works great!**

Information about my Windows 10 system.

```
$ uname -a
Linux pappa 5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Nov 23 01:01:46 \
UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy


> wsl --version
WSL-version: 1.0.3.0
Kernelversion: 5.15.79.1
WSLg-version: 1.0.47
MSRDC-version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D-version: 1.606.4
DXCore-version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows: 10.0.19045.2364

> wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Running         2
  Debian    Stopped         2

NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1070, driver 527.56
```

Apps that I tested.

```
$ thunderbird --version
 Thunderbird 102.6.1

$ mousepad --version
Mousepad 0.5.8

$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 108.0.1

$ firefox-esr --version
Mozilla Firefox 102.6.0esr
```

Even something heavy like GIMP runs fine.

```
$ gimp --version
GNU Image Manipulation Program version 2.10.30
```

**And finally...**

```
$ set | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=:0
WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0
```

Comment: FYI, only the `DISPLAY=:0` option worked with `xeyes` for me (wsl2 on up-to-date Win10).

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this same issue and couldn't get it working with any of the fixes here. Unsurprisingly, following the Microsoft Documentation on [Running GUI apps in the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps) did the trick.

First step is to install a GUI driver according to your GPU:

- [**Intel** GPU driver for WSL](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19344/intel-graphics-windows-dch-drivers.html)
- [**AMD** GPU driver for WSL](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-win-wsl-support)
- [**NVIDIA** GPU driver for WSL](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl)

Then, open up a CommandPrompt (or PowerShell) and run the following commands.

### Fresh install

If you have no prior WSL installation, run `wsl --install`.
You will need to restart your machine to finish installation, after which installation will resume. Once WSL is launched, you will be prompted for a `username` and `password`. You will need that password anytime you need to `sudo`.
If you still haven't installed any linux distro, check out this [other guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).

### Existing WSL install

If you already have WSL installed, first close any open instances of WSL.
Run `wsl --update`.
In order to restart WSL, run `wsl --shutdown`.

### Running GUI apps

Once you've installed/updated WSL, open Linux by running `wsl` from a command prompt. One final step, run: `sudo apt update`. You're done!

To verify run (or install and run) any app that requires a GUI.

#### Running Firefox

`sudo apt install firefox`
`firefox`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1150917)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Will do.

Comment: A couple of additional notes on this -- First, I mention this option in my answer, but you do go into more detail, which I think is good. However, the main problem with your answer is that the question above is specifically about Windows 10.  Your answer just won't work on Windows 10 -- As I mention in my answer, Win 10 users must upgrade to Windows 11 in order to be able to use WSLg (which is what you are recommending).

Comment: When I run `firefox`, I get `Command '/usr/bin/firefox' requires the firefox snap to be installed. Please install it with: snap install firefox`. If I run `snap install firefox` it fails with `error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/firefox": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory`. I'm on Windows 11 and `xeyes` is working for me (to prove GUI works).

Comment: @tolache have you installed firefox in your **WSL**? I mention you need to ´sudo apt install firefox´, I imagine ´snap install firefox´ is equivalent.

Comment: @MOMO Thanks for reaching out. Yes, before I did the above, I installed Firefox with `sudo apt install firefox`.

Comment: @tolache, any luck? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @Esteban unfortunately, not. Sorry. If someone figures it out, I would still be interested in the answer.

Comment: @tolache, I actually had some luck following this [thread](https://github.com/ubuntu/WSL/issues/299#issuecomment-1324102239), particularly what made `sudo snap install firefox` work for me was to include that `/etc/wsl.conf` file to activate systemd, and `sudo snap refresh` then after a wsl reboot

Answer (score 1):

sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf

and put in it:

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

if one omit this detail we get the error !! :

error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/firefox": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory

when

sudo snap install firefox

[install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-11](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-11-with-gui-support#4-configure-ubuntu)

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment as this is a new account and I did not have enough reputation. But I would like to adhere to [MOMO](https://superuser.com/users/1738276/momo) answer. Thank you!! Remember to `wsl --update`

I have similar issue as @[tolache](https://superuser.com/users/714107/tolache)

When I run firefox, I get Command '/usr/bin/firefox' requires the firefox snap to be installed. Please install it with: snap install firefox.

If I run snap install firefox it fails with error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/firefox": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory.

I'm on Windows 10. I have my GPU drivers installed. Following this [thread](https://github.com/ubuntu/WSL/issues/299) I realised my /etc/wsl.conf is already configured.

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

But, when I run `systemctl is-system-running`, it returns `offline`.

And if I run `wsl --version` in CMD/Powershell, it returns `Invalid command line option: --version`

Again, following this [thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/1679), I realised the resolution is as well `wsl --update`

So, if anyone has same situation as me, could kindly try `wsl --update` first, and followed by `wsl --shutdown`. Then only `wsl -d DistroName` to start your Linux Distro in WSL2.

And everything is working fine now. `wsl --version` is working `systemctl is-system-running` is showing `Running`. And I can `sudo snap install firefox` and launch the browser with issuing `firefox` command.

Thank you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

We recommended called [gwsl](https://opticos.github.io/gwsl/) better than old wsl did.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.