# WSL 2 running Ubuntu - X server "Can't open display"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vcxsrv

I have been setting up Ubuntu on Windows 10 WSL 2 so that I can start to ssh into a workstation at my school. I haven't had issues with ssh-ing into the remote computer, but haven't been able to open a GUI with an X server.

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Windows 10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041

Issue: Whenever I try to open an X server GUI I get this- after a minute pause:
[Can't Open Display Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzWMW.png)

I am running VcXsrv xLaunch with these settings that I have found in other guides.

> [Display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj4Sx.png) [Client startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXHuC.png) [Extra settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKpcl.png)

I make sure to run `export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0` before I make any attempts, but I have also added it to ~/.bashrc so it shouldn't really matter.

I have modified the ssh_config and sshd_config files to uncomment the X11 forwarding.

> [ssh_config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u46V.png) [sshd_config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fctyj.png)

Just in case it is important, I have been using xeyes or xclock to test.

I have been having a really tough time with this so I would appreciate absolutly anything that helps push me in the right direction. I would be happy to provide any additional information if it could help solve this issue.

Thanks to everyone!!

**Quick Edit**: I realized that I don't have a .Xauthority file and I am unable to generate one (gives `xauth: (argv):1:  unable to open display ":0".` when I try). I'm not sure if this is part of the issue.

**Edit**: Based on a suggestion from @harrymc I created a new vcxsrv profile using these flags: `"C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe" :0 -ac -terminate -lesspointer -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl -dpi auto`

I ran `netstat -abno|findstr 6000` in an admin Powershell, and got [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmlOB.png), but I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Next, I installed terminator to test my changes, but no GUI window was opened and my terminal gave me [these messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPMa1.png), with a several minute delay between [1] 47, and the second message.

**Edit**: Changed ~/.bashrc to `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`. The error remains basically the same `Error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0`. I am attempting to debug the DISPLAY command now.

Comment: Have you done all the steps in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/javarevisited/using-wsl-2-with-x-server-linux-on-windows-a372263533c3)?

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for helping!!
I completed this tutorial but I don't think it changed anything, and I'm not sure how to interpret the results. I created a new vcxsrv profile using all the flags in that guide. I tried to verify this change by running `netstat -abno|findstr 6000` in admin Powershell. [Here were the results](https://i.imgur.com/nCh1jI4.png), but I wasn't sure how to interpret them.
Finally, the guide had me install terminator and use it to test if it had worked. No GUI window opened, it only [output this to the terminal](https://i.imgur.com/nCh1jI4.png)

Comment: @harrymc I realized I used the same link twice above. The second should have been this [here](https://i.imgur.com/5036U84.png). It outputs [1] 47 first, then after a delay of 2ish minutes, it outputs the second part.

Comment: @Paul - Please [edit] your question instead of submitting numerous commentary.

Comment: You need to debug, so test first all the components of the `DISPLAY=$(...` command to see what went wrong. I would have liked better the command `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`, as is said in [this link](https://seanthegeek.net/234/graphical-linux-applications-bash-ubuntu-windows/).

Comment: I changed my ~/.bashrc to `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` as you recommended, but I haven't seen any change in the issue. I am really getting frustrated this will never work, but thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue thanks to a similar post I made on Github. Thanks to [moloned](https://github.com/moloned) there for the help.

> I changed my display to this as you suggested:
>
> `export DISPLAY="grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | sed 's/nameserver //':0"`
>
> This didn't solve this issue... BUT in that link you posted, I looked at some of >the solutions people were offering. I decided to check VcXsrv's firewall >permissions and discovered it never even created a profile for itself when I >installed it.
>
> I went to Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Defender Firewall > >Advanced Settings > Inbound Rules > New Rule...
> > Program > %ProgramFiles%\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe > Allow the connection > checked >Domain/Private/Public > Named and Confirmed Rule.
>
> And it worked!!! I've been working on this for 3 days, I don't know how it has >taken this long to find the solution, but I am so grateful for your help @moloned!

[Link to my thread on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6430)

Answer (score 4):

I came here several years later with a similar problem. As others have mentioned, none of the setting `DISPLAY` variables is necessary anymore. For me, starting X applications suddenly stopped working one day, while Wayland applications still worked.

There is a document [Diagnosing "cannot open display" type issues with WSLg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/wiki/Diagnosing-%22cannot-open-display%22-type-issues-with-WSLg) providing some possible solutions to the problem.

GUI application support in WSL2 is provided by [wslg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg). [The way it works](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/blob/main/docs/WSLg_ArchitectureOverview.png) is that it starts a separate system container with a readonly root file system, but apparently sharing the same network interface and having your container file system mounted. In the system container it starts Weston as a Wayland server and Xwayland as an X server. You can open a shell in the system container by running `wsl --system`, although you can't do much there apart from verifying that `Xwayland` is running.

Some parts of the system container are mounted into your Linux container at `/mnt/wslg`. You can inspect some log files there.

For me the problem was about [`/tmp/.X11-unix`](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/wiki/Diagnosing-%22cannot-open-display%22-type-issues-with-WSLg#x11-display-socket). It needs to be a symlink to `/mnt/wslg/.X11-unix`, but for me it was an empty directory. I temporarily fixed the problem like this:

```bash
rmdir /tmp/.X11-unix && ln -s /mnt/wslg/.X11-unix /tmp/.X11-unix
```

However, the symlink was removed again every time WSL was started. This seems to have been caused by either my `tmp.mount` or `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` of systemd, which clears the `/tmp` directory. I solved it by creating this file in `/etc/systemd/system/wslg.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=symlink /tmp/.X11-unix
After=systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=rmdir /tmp/.X11-unix
ExecStart=ln -s /mnt/wslg/.X11-unix /tmp/

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

An then enabling it using `systemctl enable wslg`.

Comment: I believe what you are seeing is related to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1834290/1210833), and I've included a link to your solution in my answer there.  Good catch on the workaround - I hadn't had a chance to investigate more in-depth yet.  I'm guessing there's a Systemd unit-file edit that can probably resolve it more properly, but this is a good workaround for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Update for users finding this question in late 2022 or later.

**Remove all *export DISPLAY* settings in your startup files!**

It's not needed anymore. With recent WSL the system takes care of that. You also don't need third-party X server software, as WSLg is now available on Windows 10 Build 19044+.

I repeat.

**You do no longer need to export the DISPLAY variable!**

You can see it is not mentioned anywhere [in the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps) anymore.

**Backstory**

I, and many with me, use non-default name servers, so I can't use that trick to refer to my local system. Instead I have a static value for IPv6 localhost in /etc/hosts.

```
# This is to always have a named host address for servers on WSL, like sshd
# Usually I use 127.0.0.1 instead.
::1     wsl
```

And the same in Windows c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Then I *had* set the DISPLAY variable in ~/.bashrc like this.

```
export DISPLAY=wsl:0.0
```

When testing both *thunderbird* and *mousepad* start fine.

But if I tried to start *firefox/firefox-esr* I got failed access to DISPLAY.

```
$ firefox-esr
Error: cannot open display: wsl:0.0
```

Basically, thunderbird *never* cared what DISPLAY was set to. Perhaps that is why it worked for me. It started even back when the variable *was* set to the wrong IP.

**But, now, with *no* DISPLAY variable manually set, firefox works great!**

Information about my Windows 10 system.

```
$ uname -a
Linux pappa 5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Nov 23 01:01:46 \
UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy


> wsl --version
WSL-version: 1.0.3.0
Kernelversion: 5.15.79.1
WSLg-version: 1.0.47
MSRDC-version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D-version: 1.606.4
DXCore-version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows: 10.0.19045.2364

> wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Running         2
  Debian    Stopped         2

NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1070, driver 527.56
```

Apps that I tested.

```
$ thunderbird --version
 Thunderbird 102.6.1

$ mousepad --version
Mousepad 0.5.8

$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 108.0.1

$ firefox-esr --version
Mozilla Firefox 102.6.0esr
```

Even something heavy like GIMP runs fine.

```
$ gimp --version
GNU Image Manipulation Program version 2.10.30
```

**And finally...** (this is with no *export DISPLAY* set anywhere)

```
$ set | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=:0
WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0
```

Comment: I can confirm that $DISPLAY is being set each time I open an xterm in WSL2. `$ echo $DISPLAY
172.28.224.1:0`

Answer (score 0):

```
export DISPLAY=$(grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | sed 's/nameserver //'):0
```

I suspect HTML or the markdown tool ate your backquotes. The above is working for me in my .profile running bash shell from a pretty fresh WSL2 Unbuntu installation. I'm not currently willing to install the Windows development version for native gpu support, but VcXsrv works fine for now.

Comment: As a heads-up - (A) For most people, assuming a default installation of WSL2, the easiest method is just `export DISPLAY=$(hostname).local:0` which uses [mDNS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407064/11810933).  (B) You no longer need a "development version" to get WSLg.  There's an optional Windows update that is required, but it doesn't even require Insider (and will be automatically moved to the non-Preview in a few weeks).  See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1669770/1210833) for information on how to update.

Answer (score 0):

[@NoSubstitute's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1758744/723971) is correct, what I was missing is that I had to update my WSL.
I was on WSL 2, but apparently WSLg, the part that makes WSL compatible with Wayland/X server, is bundled in the newer versions.

I've done the following steps to update:

- `wsl --update`
- `wsl --shutdown` (will restart wsl)

Then you can run `env | grep DISPLAY` and see that the required vars are set.

Answer (score 0):

For users with old(ish) WSL2 Ubuntu installation who experiencing `Can't open display` error, the easy fix is:

```
wsl --unregister ubuntu
wsl --install -d ubuntu
wsl --update
```

Run Ubuntu --> register your user name and password, then:

```
# Install X-service
sudo apt update
sudo apt install x11-apps
# Test
env | grep -i display
# Should return:
# WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0
# DISPLAY=:0
xeyes &
xcalc
```