# Cannot open graphical applications in WSL2 on Arch, but works on Ubuntu

Tags: wsl2

I am trying to run a program with a GUI on Arch, but it complains that it cannot initialize GTK.
The same program works perfectly fine on Ubuntu. Both distributions have `DISPLAY` set to `:0`.

Graphical programs were working as expected a few days ago, and I do not remember changing anything which could be relevant.

I have tried launching an X server using `XLaunch`, which did not appear to have any effect.
Restarting WSL and my computer did not fix the issue, and neither did updating Arch or WSL.
Launching different graphical programs, such as `gtkwave` or `xterm`, had the same result. (xterm says `Can't open display :0`)
Going back in time did not work, as I do not have access to a time machine.
The programs do run as expected in Ubuntu, however I would prefer to use Arch when possible.

Comment: Glad you reposted this over here.  Repeating and expanding on my question/comment on SO - **(1)** Any Systemd in play in either of the WSL instances? **(2)** Is it just GTK apps? Does a non-GTK graphical app (e.g. `xterm`) launch in Arch?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Both have `systemd=true` in `/etc/wsl.conf`, however I do not know if that is what I am looking for. xterm does not work (see above)

Comment: Ah, oops - Failed to read the part about `xterm` that is so clearly there - Apologies and thanks.  Let me do some testing - It's been a while since I looked at this, but I seem to recall that if two distros are running Systemd in WSL, there are issues with the display.

Comment: What's your `wsl --version`?  Just thinking through the fact that it was *"working as expected a few days ago"*.  There was a new WSL release last week, but there really isn't much in the way of release notes, other than "minor" that might indicate a change that could break this.

Comment: WSL version is 2.1.4.0, kernel is 5.15.146.1-2, wslg is 1.0.60

Comment: If you don't need Systemd, it's probably worth setting both to `syste,d=false` (or just commenting out) in the `/etc/wsl.conf` to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Okay, `2.1.4.0` is the latest, so the fact that it updated *could* be the thing that changed.

Comment: seems disabling systemd worked

Comment: Good to hear, I guess.  Most likely something in the way `/mnt/wslg` is being mounted (or not) when Systemd is running in both distros.  Like I said, it's been a while since I looked at that particular combination - I tend to [avoid Systemd in WSL](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986) unless I need it for testing something in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved (at least with a workaround) in the comments.  And I've now seen what seem to be 3 related questions in the last week about this, so there may be significant issue.

I *believe* there's a common theme of:

1. Recent update of WSL2 to 2.1.5 (or 1 previous beta)
2. Systemd being enabled
3. Non-Ubuntu (perhaps non-Debian) distribution

If you don't have at least the first two of these, then you are probably looking at a different issue.  I'm guessing it's *possible* for the problem to occur on Ubuntu, but something about the current Systemd loading order on that distro appears to be working to avoid the issue for the most part.

For this particular quetion, the issue was caused when running Systemd inside Arch on WSL2 release 2.1.4, and the issue resolved when disabling Systemd.

That leads up to ...

##### Option 1: Disable Systemd

If you do not need Systemd in WSL.  Run:

```
sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf
```

If you have:

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

Then either comment out the `system` line or set it to `false`.

Shutdown WSL (or terminate the instance) and restart. This can be done via PowerShell with:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

##### Option 2: Create a link for the X11 socket

If you still need or want to run Systemd, there's another answer [here on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1834709/1210833) with a solution that I believe is likely to resolve the issue.  The solution from that answer is to:

```
rmdir /tmp/.X11-unix && ln -s /mmnt/wslg/.X11-unix /tmp/.X11-unix
```

That answer also includes a Systemd unit to automatically handle this on every boot.  However, I do recommend occasionally checking to see if there are reports of the issue being fixed, so that you can stop this manually linking in the future. It's *possible* (but not expected) for this to interfere with other behavior.

---

For reference, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78151724/11810933) (currently closed, but will probably be Roomba'd at some point) is another case, with a WSL update, OpenSUSE Tumbleweed, and Systemd enabled.  Disabling Systemd also resolved that case.

Comment: I shouldn't have to say this (and I can't in the answer itself, but can as a comment), but if you find the information in [the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1834709/1210833) that I linked here helpful, I'd much rather you upvote *that user's answer* than mine, as it is the original source.