# WSL Ubuntu: Cannot start Terminator

Tags: ubuntu, wsl2, terminator

I installed WSL Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10. I also installed VcXsrv (Xlaunch). I use the command as follows to start VcXsrv:

```
 "C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe" :0 -ac -terminate -lesspointer -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl -dpi auto
```

At Ubuntu terminal, I am not able to start terminator. Please help.

```
$ export DISPLAY=0:0
$ terminator
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
You need to run terminator in an X environment. Make sure $DISPLAY is properly set.
```

Below is the output of netstat

```
C:\Windows\system32>netstat -abno|findstr 6000
  TCP    0.0.0.0:6000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       42548
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6000         127.0.0.1:65381        ESTABLISHED     42548
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6000         127.0.0.1:65382        ESTABLISHED     42548
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6000         127.0.0.1:65383        ESTABLISHED     42548
  TCP    127.0.0.1:65381        127.0.0.1:6000         ESTABLISHED     42548
  TCP    127.0.0.1:65382        127.0.0.1:6000         ESTABLISHED     42548
  TCP    127.0.0.1:65383        127.0.0.1:6000         ESTABLISHED     42548
  TCP    [::]:6000              [::]:0                 LISTENING       42548
```

```
 Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter |? { $_.Program -like "*vcxsrv*" } | Get-NetFirewallRule


Name                          : TCP Query User{81BBD37C-DC9F-4C50-B2C6-A1B58CABD66C}C:\program files\vcxsrv\vcxsrv.exe
DisplayName                   : VcXsrv windows xserver
Description                   : VcXsrv windows xserver
DisplayGroup                  :
Group                         :
Enabled                       : True
Profile                       : Domain
Platform                      : {}
Direction                     : Inbound
Action                        : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy           : DeferToUser
LooseSourceMapping            : False
LocalOnlyMapping              : False
Owner                         :
PrimaryStatus                 : OK
Status                        : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus             : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource             : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType         : Local
RemoteDynamicKeywordAddresses :

Name                          : {14B2C126-9C6A-42CA-B496-62F2D88ED067}
DisplayName                   : VcXsrv windows xserver
Description                   : VcXsrv windows xserver
DisplayGroup                  :
Group                         :
Enabled                       : True
Profile                       : Public
Platform                      : {}
Direction                     : Inbound
Action                        : Block
EdgeTraversalPolicy           : Block
LooseSourceMapping            : False
LocalOnlyMapping              : False
Owner                         :
PrimaryStatus                 : OK
Status                        : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus             : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource             : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType         : Local
RemoteDynamicKeywordAddresses :

Name                          : UDP Query User{87720067-4851-485C-A9B1-ABE74E6BE131}C:\program files\vcxsrv\vcxsrv.exe
DisplayName                   : VcXsrv windows xserver
Description                   : VcXsrv windows xserver
DisplayGroup                  :
Group                         :
Enabled                       : True
Profile                       : Domain
Platform                      : {}
Direction                     : Inbound
Action                        : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy           : DeferToUser
LooseSourceMapping            : False
LocalOnlyMapping              : False
Owner                         :
PrimaryStatus                 : OK
Status                        : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus             : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource             : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType         : Local
RemoteDynamicKeywordAddresses :

Name                          : {1B4ABAF3-28C3-42F8-8C62-3AE54EFFC97C}
DisplayName                   : VcXsrv windows xserver
Description                   : VcXsrv windows xserver
DisplayGroup                  :
Group                         :
Enabled                       : True
Profile                       : Public
Platform                      : {}
Direction                     : Inbound
Action                        : Block
EdgeTraversalPolicy           : Block
LooseSourceMapping            : False
LocalOnlyMapping              : False
Owner                         :
PrimaryStatus                 : OK
Status                        : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus             : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource             : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType         : Local
RemoteDynamicKeywordAddresses :
```

Comment: Ah, I missed the part about this being VcXsrv/XLaunch on your [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73201980/11810933).  Did you happen to read the answers I posted in a comment to your question?  They have the correct `DISPLAY` variable that you'll need to use under WSL2 with VcXsrv.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run GUI apps with Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1580610/how-to-run-gui-apps-with-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

Comment: Specifically, see @harrymc's answer to that question with `export DISPLAY=$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2>/dev/null):0` or my answer with `export DISPLAY=$(hostname).local:0`.  Let me know (via edit) if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: And you can see the reason *why* you need this in my (also off-topic) [Stack Overflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407064/11810933).

Comment: No luck. It does not work.

$ export DISPLAY=$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2>/dev/null):0
$ export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
pluo@PerryLuo-PC:~$ terminator
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
You need to run terminator in an X environment. Make sure $DISPLAY is properly set

Comment: Is there a firewall rule in place?  From an administrative PowerShell, check `Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter |? { $_.Program -like "*vcxsrv*" } | Get-NetFirewallRule`.

Comment: Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter |? { $_.Program -like "*vcxsrv*" } | Get-NetFirewallRule
This command gives a long list of output. I have no clue how to interpret it. Which items I should check?

Comment: There are probably 4 rules that result (each probably starts with `Name`).  Make sure each one is `Enabled (True)`, `Profile (Public)`, and points to the correct path for `vcxsrv.exe`.

Comment: I pasted output. It looks fine. Any idea?

Comment: Firewall rules look good.  Next, I'd try hard-coding the IP address of the Windows host into the variable, something like `export DISPLAY=192.168.1.10:0` (or whatever the host IP is).  You aren't using a VPN or any sort, right?

Comment: It works!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Good to hear!  Still a bit concerned here that `export DISPLAY=$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2>/dev/null):0` didn't work for you.  That may indicate some other sort of name resolution issue that *could* cause you other problems down the line, but worry about that if/when it happens.  Just keep this comment in mind if you do run into future problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had originally voted to close this as a duplicate of the general [How to run GUI apps with Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://superuser.com/q/1580610/1210833) question, but the reality is that it's a bit different.

We really don't have a general-purpose, *"How do I determine the correct `DISPLAY` variable for WSL?"* question  Since we ended up troubleshooting this in the comments, let me go through the various options here in an answer.

First, some "search terms".  You may encounter different errors when attempting to run Linux GUI applications in WSL:

- `Error: Unable to open display`
- `Error E233: cannot open display`
- `Error: (SDL_Init) No available video device` (from SDL apps)
- `Error: An OpenGL context could not be created`

First, do read [How to run GUI apps with Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://superuser.com/q/1580610/1210833).  You will need to choose one of those solutions in order to run Linux GUI applications in WSL.

But if you are still having issues, then you may need to take additional steps.

##### WSL2:  Windows 11 with WSLg

If you are using Windows 11 with WSLg (the default WSL option for running Linux GUI apps in Windows 11), then your `DISPLAY` variable should be set by WSL for you.  It should be:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

This is the equivalent of `DISPLAY=localhost:0`, because WSLg runs inside the WSL2 VM, so it is "local" to your WSL session.

The firewall rules should also be set for you automatically.

And you should have:

```
$ echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY
wayland-0
```

For running Wayland applications (the successor to X).

If these variables aren't set properly:

- Check your startup config files to see if you (or an application you installed) is setting the `DISPLAY` to something else there.

  Try starting WSL (from PowerShell) without running your Bash startup with:

  ```
  wsl ~ -e bash --noprofile --norc
  ```

  And then check the variables again.  If they are correct now, then *something* in your startup is changing them.  You'll need to edit your startup config, find the culprit, and fix it.
- Are you running a Systemd enablement script?  If so, try without it.  By default the Systemd environment does not have the `DISPLAY` (and other built-in WSL variables).  Most Systemd-enablement scripts will attempt to handle this, but it may have run into a corner-case that it didn't expect.

##### WSL1:  Windows 10 or 11 with a third-party X server

When using a third-party X server like VcXsrv (as in the original question here) in WSL1, the `DISPLAY` should again be `:0`, as with WSLg above.

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

WSL1 runs *in the same network* as the Windows host, so VcXsrv (etc.) will be *local* to WSL1.

No special firewall rules are required when running WSL1 with a third-party Windows X server.

##### WSL2: Windows 10 or 11 with a third-party X server

This is the most complicated case, and the one covered by the original question.  You need at least two things in place to communicate with VcXsrv (etc.) under WSL2:

- The correct IP address for the `DISPLAY` variable.
- Firewall rules to allow access

Both of these are needed because WSL2 runs in a *separate network* than the Windows host.  It runs using a virtual network interface behind a virtual switch that is NAT'd.  As a result, `localhost:0` (or just `:0`) refers to the *WSL2* network interface, *not* the Windows host.

In a default WSL2 configuration, the DNS resolver is set (by WSL) to the Windows host, using the IP address of that virtual switch.  As a result, you can try several options for determining the correct IP for the `DISPLAY`:

- `export DISPLAY="$(hostname).local:0"`

  This uses mDNS, which has been available in WSL2 for the last few years.  See [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407064/11810933) for more information.  This does require that the default resolver is used.
- `export DISPLAY=$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2>/dev/null):0`

  This parses the `/etc/resolv.conf` to obtain the IP address of the Windows host where the resolver is running.  Again, this requires that the default WSL2 resolver is in use.
- `export DISPLAY=$(host` hostname --long `| grep -oP '(\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}' | tail -1 | awk '{ print $NF }' | tr -d '\r')`

  If the above two options don't work, then (credit [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418823/1165986), then this option will attempt to obtain the Windows IP address of the *primary* network interface.  Typically this is a private-network address like `192.168.1.100` or `10.0.1.5`.

  If this address is static, you can simply hard-code it, which worked for the OP:

  ```
  export DISPLAY=192.168.1.100:0` # Adjust with your actual IP
  ```

  If it is dynamically assigned and changes frequently, then you can use the above command to attempt to obtain it.  However, note that this is *much* slower than any other method.  It takes around 3 seconds on my relatively fast system to complete.

##### Firewall rules

When using WSL2 with a third-party X server, you'll also need to make sure that the firewall is allowing access from WSL2 to the Windows host.

The first time you attempt a connection to the X server, Windows Defender *should* display a dialog where you can allow access from Public and/or Private networks.  Unfortunately, the WSL2 network is considered "Public" from the Windows host, so you'll need to make sure Public is selected.

Note:  In my experience, the dialog often comes up *behind* other windows, and can be easily missed.  If this happens, and that dialog is closed without Allowing the traffic, then a "Deny" rule will likely be put in place.

However, a public "Allow" rule here also means that the firewall will allow traffic on that port on other Public networks (like public wifi networks).  This can be a security risk, if you do run the X server when not on your home network.

First, make sure that the rules are in place to *allow* access, at least.  From an administrative PowerShell session:

```
Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter |? { $_.Program -like "*vcxsrv*" } | Get-NetFirewallRule
```

Adjust the `-like` option for the executable for your X server.

It's probably easiest at this point to look for the `DisplayName` in the output.  Then run *Windows Defender Firewall* from the Start menu and find the associate rules in *Inbound Rules*.  Make sure that there are "Allow" rules in place for (at least) Public networks.

This answer has gotten a bit long, and adding information on limiting the firewall rule to traffic coming from WSL2 (as opposed other Public networks) is probably a bit out of scope.  If someone is interested in how to do this, please post a separate question on that particular topic.