# unable to launch google-chrome in WSL2 / Ubuntu 22.0.4.2 LTS after installing Ubuntu for another windows user

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11, wsl2, ubuntu-22.04

Even tho I had WSL2 / Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS installed in one Windows user account (hereinafter referred to as user A) I wanted it working in another user account (hereinafter referred to as user B) on the same computer. For user B I had to go to "Turn Windows features on or off" and turn it on even tho it was already on user A.

I then installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS from the Microsoft Store and was able to load Ubuntu 22.04.2 for user B. I then went to user A's account and tried to run `google-chrome` from that other account. I had been able to do so before I had installed WSL2 / Ubuntu for user B but now I'm not able to do so. Any attempt to do so gets me this error:

```
[244:272:0427/083045.657761:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0427/083047.041860:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[0427/083047.044229:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[0427/083047.044260:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[0427/083047.046110:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir /home/scbn/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/attachments/4ac62951-ad00-4bc5-9929-e535694323de: No such file or directory (2)
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

When I try to run google-chrome from user B's Ubuntu WSL2 instance I get a different error (altho the first part is the same):

```
[4047:4073:0427/044727.454515:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[4047:4047:0427/044727.456461:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(239)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[4047:4047:0427/044727.456495:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
```

Any ideas?

`wsl -l -v` returns this:

```
wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04    Running         2
```

One thing that's a little weird...  when I do `wsl --version` for user B I get this:

```
Invalid command line option: --version
```

But when I do `wsl --version` for user A I get this:

```
WSL version: 1.2.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.51
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.1555
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you perform a shutdown on WSL before you switched users?

Comment: @Ramhound - I just logged into both accounts and did`wsl --shutdown` on each account. `wsl --version`. I then started WSL / Ubuntu under user A and got the same outcome. I did`wsl --shutdown` on user A and then tried the same thing under user B. Same thing. The error messages differ slightly for each user but the first part is exactly the same. I added the other error message to my orig post.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7915) bug report has some resolutions that likely will resolve the problem.  I suspect you have conflicting WSL2 environments installed.  So I would run `wsl --update` to make sure the environment is updated. WSL2 requires `Virtual Machine Platform` to be installed.  Did you install WSL through the optional features or through the command that installs the WSL version from the Microsoft Store? [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1580610) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69621197/running-cypress-on-wsl) might be helpful

Comment: Any new information you have to share should be in the form of an [edit] to your question instead of a temporary flag. I won't receive notification of a comment, when you modify your question, I will receive notification.